# Automated WebForm Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bunch of C# functions with string, int and bool arguments that serve as data entry interfaces.  I'd like to be able to create a webform for each method; a textbox for each string/int and a checkbox for each bool.

Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use reflection to retrieve the methods' signature and then create a web form based on its parameter

```
// Create a container (panel for instance)

var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{
  if (parameter.ParameterType == typeof(string))
  {//Create a text box and add it to the panel}
  else if (parameter.ParameterType == typeof(int))
  {//Create a numeric box and add it to the panel}
...
}
```